# Possible orders of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that K is a subgroup of D<sub>35</sub> and K contains at least two reflections . What are the possible orders of K ?

Any order of K must divide 70 . So possible orders of K are {1,2,5,7,10,14,35,70} . How to use the other condition to reduce the size of this set ? 
I am aware of the fact that every subgroup of the dihedral group is either cyclic or dihedral. 
General form of dihedral group 
D<sub>n</sub> = { 1, r , r<sup>2</sup>,...,r<sup>n-1</sup>,f,r.f,...,r<sup>n-1</sup>.f}
If K contains r<sup>i</sup>f and r<sup>j</sup>f ,it will contain r<sup>i-j</sup>.

Comment: I don't get why this question is down voted. Any suggestion will be well appreciated.

Comment: If it contains at least two reflections then it is clear that it cannot have order $1,2,5,7$, or $35$.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit ?

Comment: If $K$ contains 1 reflexion then it also contains the group generated by that reflexion. If it contains two reflexion then it also contains the group generated by this two reflexions. Using the fact that order of subgroups divides order of group you should be able to narrow it down.